# Convergence of Random Variables and Median.

Tags: probability, statistics, median

Let $\{X_{n}\}_{n}$ be a sequence of real random variables and let $X$ be a real random variable such that $\lim_{n} X_{n}(\omega) = X(\omega)$. Assume that $X_{n}(\omega)$ is a monotone decreasing sequence. My question is whther or not we have that
\begin{equation}\nonumber
\lim_{n} Med(X_{n}) = Med(X),
\end{equation}
where $Med(\cdot)$ denotes the univariate median.

Answer (score 0):

It is true. This hypothesis are equivalent to say that $X_{n}$ converges almost surely to $X$. It implies that $X_{n}$ converges in probability to $X$. By [Convergence in probability implies convergence of the median?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2792833/convergence-in-probability-implies-convergence-of-the-median) we have that it implies the convergence of the medians.